# variable define but not working in javascript while this represent window

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

i have a little code snippet below

```
var foo = {
    bar: function () {
        return this.baz;
    },
    baz: 1
};
(function () {
    return typeof arguments[0]();
})(foo.bar);
baz = 1;
//result undefined
```

when the `foo.bar` function is executed, `this` refers to the window scope which of course knows nothing about `baz` so i have defined `baz=1` in window. but the program still not working and returning `undefined`. why it is returning `undefined` while `baz` have defined in window and i am executing foo.bar from window

Comment: adding a blank line before your code would make it display correctly.

Comment: If you do `bar: function () { console.log(this); return this.baz; }` you can see that `this` refers to its parent, which is `arguments`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you execute the function like `arguments[0]()`, then `this` is referring to the `arguments` object, which doesn't have the property `baz`, so it will still be `undefined`.

You could bind `this` to a certain object by:

`arguments[0].call(foo)` or `arguments[0].apply(foo)`.

Answer (score 0):

"this" becomes scoped the bar function.  If you change it to return foo.baz, it'll work

Answer (score -1):

`foo.baz` will work , but not `this.baz`. try reading the scopes in javascript

Comment: Because “try reading the scopes in javascript” doesn’t make sense, and this doesn’t answer the actual question of “why”.